# How to get the Nth arrangement in a Combinatoric sequence and vice-versa?

Tags: algorithm, math, combinations, combinatorics, sequences

how do I get the **Nth** arrangement out of all possible combinations of arranging 4 indistinguishable balls in 3 distinct buckets. if `Bl` = `number of balls` and `Bk` = `number of buckets` e.g. for **Bl** = 4, **Bk** = 3 the possible arrangements are :

`004`,`013`,`022`,`031`,`040`,`103`,`112`,`121`,`130`,`202`,`211`,`220`,`301`,`310`,`400` .

the first arrangement(**N=0**) is `004`(*i.e. bucket 1 = 0 balls*, *bucket 2 = 0 balls*, *bucket 3 = 4 balls*) and the last(**N=14**) is `400`. so say I have `103` **N** would be equal to **5**. I want to be able to do

```
int Bl=4,Bk=3;
getN(004,Bl,Bk);// which should be = 0
getNthTerm(8,Bl,Bk);// which should be = 130
```

> **P.S:** max number of terms for the sequence is  **(Bl+Bk-1)C(Bk-1)** where **C** is the combinatorics/combination  operator. *`Obtained from`* [*`stars and bars`*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))

Comment: These are called [Integer Compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)). More specifically _Restricted Integer Compositions_. I'm not sure of how to get the `nth` one.

Comment: Thanks Joseph I would look that up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no faster way of doing this than combinatorial decomposition which takes roughly O(Bl) time.

We simply compute the number of balls which go into the each bucket for the selected index, working one bucket at a time. For each possible assignment to the bucket we compute the number of possible arrangements of the remaining balls and buckets. If the index is less than that number, we select that arrangement; otherwise we put one more ball in the bucket and subtract the number of arrangements we just skipped from the index.

Here's a C implementation. I didn't include the `binom` function in the implementation below. It's usually best to precompute the binomial coefficients over the range of values you are interested in, since there won't normally be too many. It is easy to do the computation incrementally but it requires a multiplication and a division at each step; while that doesn't affect the asymptotic complexity, it makes the inner loop much slower (because of the divide) and increases the risk of overflow (because of the multiply).

```
/* Computes arrangement corresponding to index.
 * Returns 0 if index is out of range.
 */
int get_nth(long index, int buckets, int balls, int result[buckets]) {
  int i = 0;
  memset(result, 0, buckets * sizeof *result);
  --buckets;
  while (balls && buckets) {
    long count = binom(buckets + balls - 1, buckets - 1);
    if (index < count) { --buckets; ++i; }
    else { ++result[i]; --balls; index -= count; }
  }
  if (balls) result[i] = balls;
  return index == 0;
}
```

Comment: @mbo: or `count = binom(...` :). I also missed the `index -= count`. Now I've tested it a bit, and it seems to work as advertised. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are some interesting bijections that can be made. Finally, we can use ranking and unranking methods for the regular k-combinations, which are more common knowledge.

1. A bijection from the number of balls in each bucket to the ordered multiset of choices of buckets; for example: `[3, 1, 0]  -->  [1, 1, 1, 2]` (three choices of 1 and one choice of 2).
2. A bijection from the k-subsets of `{1...n}` (with repetition) to k-subsets of `{1...n + k − 1}` (without repetition) by mapping `{c_0, c_1...c_(k−1)}` to `{c_0, c_(1+1), c_(2+2)...c_(k−1+k−1)}` (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/144408/indexing-combinations-with-repetition)).

Here's some python code:

```py
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

def toTokens(C):
  return map(lambda x: int(x), list(C))

def compositionToChoice(tokens):
  result = []
  for i, t in enumerate(tokens):
    result = result + [i + 1] * t
  return result

def bijection(C):
  result = []
  k = 0
  for i, _c in enumerate(C):
    result.append(C[i] + k)
    k = k + 1
  return result

compositions = ['004','013','022','031','040','103','112',
                '121','130','202','211','220','301','310','400']

for c in compositions:
  tokens = toTokens(c)
  choices = compositionToChoice(tokens)
  combination = bijection(choices)
  print "%s  -->  %s  -->  %s" % (tokens, choices, combination)
```

Output:

```py
"""
[0, 0, 4]  -->  [3, 3, 3, 3]  -->  [3, 4, 5, 6]
[0, 1, 3]  -->  [2, 3, 3, 3]  -->  [2, 4, 5, 6]
[0, 2, 2]  -->  [2, 2, 3, 3]  -->  [2, 3, 5, 6]
[0, 3, 1]  -->  [2, 2, 2, 3]  -->  [2, 3, 4, 6]
[0, 4, 0]  -->  [2, 2, 2, 2]  -->  [2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 0, 3]  -->  [1, 3, 3, 3]  -->  [1, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 1, 2]  -->  [1, 2, 3, 3]  -->  [1, 3, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 1]  -->  [1, 2, 2, 3]  -->  [1, 3, 4, 6]
[1, 3, 0]  -->  [1, 2, 2, 2]  -->  [1, 3, 4, 5]
[2, 0, 2]  -->  [1, 1, 3, 3]  -->  [1, 2, 5, 6]
[2, 1, 1]  -->  [1, 1, 2, 3]  -->  [1, 2, 4, 6]
[2, 2, 0]  -->  [1, 1, 2, 2]  -->  [1, 2, 4, 5]
[3, 0, 1]  -->  [1, 1, 1, 3]  -->  [1, 2, 3, 6]
[3, 1, 0]  -->  [1, 1, 1, 2]  -->  [1, 2, 3, 5]
[4, 0, 0]  -->  [1, 1, 1, 1]  -->  [1, 2, 3, 4]
"""
```